# Keras model compile error: TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len() model.compile

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the above error when trying to do the following:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=params.get('lr'), decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy', f1_score])
```

Error:

> TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()

Comment: You should give more codes.Where is `len()`?

Comment: Please include the full backtrace of the error.